# Spring Batch Application Not Stopping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have configured my spring batch job like below

```
         @Bean
        public Job myJob(Step myStep,JobRepository jobRepository) {
            return new JobBuilder("sampleJob", jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(myStep)
                    .on("*")
                    .end()
                    .end().build();
           }
```

I want to schedule it . So I have configured it like below

```
@Component
public class MyJobScheduler {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
    public void launchJob() throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobParametersInvalidException, JobRestartException {
        jobLauncher.run(job,new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

The application is not stopping after job completion. However, without `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled` , the app shuts down after the job completes. How do I shut down app as soon as job completes and trigger it again after an hour(as per my cron expression)?

I have tried to stop the job by following [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/job-scheduler-example/) link but  class is not there . My IDE is complaining that it cannot find `SpringBatchScheduler` bean.

Comment: Does the job stop when you run it in a `main` method without scheduling? Is the job not stopping or the app not stopping? Because the app could continue the execution after the job is done to run subsequent schedules.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes, the app is not stopping . The app shuts down fine when I run main method without scheduling. I have edited the questiion

Answer (score 0):

> How do I shut down app as soon as job completes and trigger it again after an hour(as per my cron expression)?

In that case, you need to schedule the app from ***outside*** the JVM (with `crontab` or another scheduler).

If you want to schedule job executions using Spring's scheduling features, you need to keep the JVM running and Spring will launches your job according to the defined schedule.